# Number of solutions of $x^d = 1_G$ .

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group (not necessarily abelian). Let $d \mid |G|$, where $d \in \mathbb{N}$. Does there exist at least $d$ solutions to the equation $x^d = 1_G$ for $x \in G$?

I can prove it for abelian groups (Not hard).

Is it true for all groups? If not please give counterexample.

Comment: See also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/109027/applications-of-frobenius-theorem-and-conjecture

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is Frobenius theorem.

> Suppose $G$ is a finite group such that $d$ divides $|G|$. Then the number of solutions to $x^d = 1$ is a multiple of $d$.

Since the identity is always a solution, there exist at least $d$ solutions. This is true for all finite groups, but it is not very easy to prove.

A proof can be found in the following Monthly article:

> I. M. Isaacs, G. R. Robinson, *On a Theorem of Frobenius: Solutions of $x^n = 1$ in finite groups*, Amer. Math. Monthly, Vol. 99, No. 4, 352-354, (1992).

The theorem can be generalized in many different ways. A proof of the following generalization is given in Marshall Hall's group theory book:

> Let $G$ be a finite group and $C$ a conjugacy class of $G$. The number of elements $x$ such that $x^n \in C$ is a multiple of $\gcd(n|C|, |G|)$.

The original theorem follows from the case $C = \{1\}$.